# Create own EventHandler from DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler - is this possible?

Tags: c#, delegates, eventhandler

Good evening,
I try to create an own EventHandler on the base of the DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler.
The reason is, I want to give the Callback function an extra parameter (fileName).
This is my EventHandler:

```
 public class MyDownloadProgressChangedEventHandler : DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler
    {

        public object Sender { get; set; }

        public DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs E { get; set; }

        public string FileName { get; set; }

        public MyDownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e, string fileName)
        {
            this.Sender = sender;
            this.E = e;
            this.FileName = fileName;
        }

    }
```

And this is my attempt:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

client.DownloadProgressChanged += new MyDownloadProgressChangedEventhandler(DownloadProgressChanged);
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(String.Format("{0}/key={1}", srv, file)), localName);

Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Download of file {0} started.", localName));
Console.ReadLine();
```

But VS says that a conversation from MyDownloadProgressChangedEventHandler to the DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler is not possible.
Is this even possible like how I think?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How should the WebClient know what to put inside your defined variable? (it can't)

Instead, wrap the handler you got inside another one:

```
string fileName = new Uri(String.Format("{0}/key={1}", srv, file));
client.DownloadProgressChanged += 
    (sender, e) =>
        DownloadProgressChanged(sender, e, fileName);
client.DownloadFileAsync(fileName);
```

Lambda expressions are always fun to use in these situations!

Comment: Yep, Delegates behave strangely compared to normal classes when it comes to inheritance :) (it's inverted) Also, usually it's even easier to create a complete new delegate instead.